# Como mudar a cor ao desenhar um segmento de reta que pertence a um círculo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, equações

Estou tentando desenhar em uma imagem `400 × 400`. O primeiro desenho é uma reta definida pela equação `ax + by + c = 0`. Quando substituir `x` e `y` e o resultado for 0 o ponto pertence a reta, então mudo a cor para azul.

O outro desenho é um círculo definido por `(x - xc)² + (y – yc)² = R²`, onde a raiz da primeira parte é igual ao raio (R). Para saber se um ponto pertence ao círculo, comparo a distancia (d) do ponto P(x, y) ao centro e, se esse valor for igual ao raio, o ponto pertence à circunferência e, se for menor, é interno ao círculo.

Até ai tudo bem, mas preciso que a parte da reta que fica dentro do círculo fique com uma cor diferente do restante da reta. Alguém sabe com fazer isso?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def eqReta(x, y, pA=[0, 0], pB=[5, 5]):
    a = pA[1] - pB[1]  # a = (ya - yb)
    b = pB[0] - pA[0]  # b = (xb - xa)
    c = (pA[0] * pB[1]) - (pB[0] * pA[1])  # c = xayb - xbya
    f = int(a * x + b * y + c)  # equacao geral
    return f == 0  # ponto x, y pertence a reta


def eqCirculo(x, y, center=[150, 200], r=75):
    d = int(np.sqrt((x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2))
    if d > r:  # ponto x, y fora do circulo
        return -1
    if d < r:  # ponto x, y interno ao circulo
        return 0
    if d == r:  # ponto x, y esta na borda do circulo
        return 1


plano = np.ones((400, 400, 3)) * 255

for x in range(plano.shape[0]):
    for y in range(plano.shape[1]):
        if eqCirculo(x, y) == 1:
            plano[x, y] = [0, 0, 255]

        if eqReta(x, y) == 1:
            plano[x, y] = [255, 0, 0]
cv2.imshow("Canvas", plano)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

O codigo que ja tenho gera essa imagem:

[image: circul e reta]

Comment: parabéns pela pergunta! Upvote na certa!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você já tem a resposta para a sua pergunta. Se você sabe como verificar se um ponto pertence ao [círculo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%ADrculo), basta fazer a seguinte verificação para cada ponto da reta que você for pintar:

[image]

E o seu código já faz isso. Veja que a função `eqCircle` retorna `-1` se o ponto está fora do círculo, `0` se é interno ao círculo e `1` se pertence à circunferência.

Portanto, basta mudar a cor ao imprimir um dos pontos da reta se o valor de `eqCirculo` tiver retornado `0` (ou seja, o ponto é interno à circunferência). Só precisaremos mexer na parte do `for`.

Assim:

```
for x in range(plano.shape[0]):
    for y in range(plano.shape[1]):
        resultadoCirculo = eqCirculo(x, y)

        # Se pertence à reta:
        if eqReta(x, y) == 1:
            if resultadoCirculo == 0:
                # Verde se o ponto é interno à circunferência.
                plano[x, y] = [0, 255, 0]
            else:
                # Vermelho se o ponto é externo à circunferência.
                plano[x, y] = [255, 0, 0]

        if resultadoCirculo == 1:
            plano[x, y] = [0, 0, 255]  # Azul se pertence à circunferência.
```

O resultado será algo assim:

[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: Eu **realmente** adorei responder a essa pergunta. Primeiro porque nunca tinha mexido com essa biblioteca do Python. Segundo e mais significativo porque ano passado estudei introdução à geometria analítica na escola e pensei que ainda iria demorar para achar uma aplicação prática. Ora, me enganei: aqui está! :D Massa demais...

Comment: Programar é uma  forma  realmente eficiente  para treinar matematica.

Comment: @Luiz Felipe, resposta elegante e concisa. +1.

Comment: @LuizFelipe parabéns! Que resposta sensacional! Quem dera as Universidades tivessem, professores no curso de matemática como você para alguma disciplina prática com certos exercícios incríveis como este exemplo. Meus parabéns cara, desejo muito sucesso a você!